# Private const in Class NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, private

Well comrades, i have a issue that keep me from sleeping, i have this function:

```
class iniparser {
constructor (path) {
    this.path = path;
}

#_getValue (data, param) {
    const iniparam = /^\s*([\w\.\-\_]+)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$/;
    let value;

    data.toString().match(/.*?\n|.+$/g).forEach(function(line) {
        if (iniparam.test(line) && line.match(iniparam)[1] === param) {
            value = line.match(iniparam)[2];
        }
    });

    return value;
}
```

and then some public method to work with and all of that... The problem is iniparam, i want make it private, becouse i have a _setValue method that need the constant, and i want to write good code, i check [TC39](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) but even using tons and tons of examples i can get it working. Please some soul help me.

Comment: If this class is in a module by itself, then just define `iniparam` as a `const` at the module level since there's no particular reason it needs to be an instance property or a class property.  Then any methods in the class can use it, but it's not available outside the module as long as you don't export it.  Module level definitions that aren't exported are private by design.

Comment: Btw, use either `#` or `_`, but not both

Comment: @jfriend00 This. And actually the same could be said about `getValue` as a whole, it's not a method as it doesn't use `this` but rather should be a module-level function.

Comment: @Bergi - Yeah, I assumed that there was a reason somewhere for it to be a method, but perhaps not.  It could also just be a utility function declared at the module level.

Comment: @Bergi can i ask you why? its just bad practice or can generate an error?

Comment: @jfriend00 you mean declare it before class iniparser?

Comment: @ValentinoZaffrani Just a bad practice. Leading underscores are used to mark methods that should not be used from elsewhere ("private by convention"). But making the method actually private with `#` already takes care of that.

Comment: Yes, as a module level variable before the `class` definition.  It's very common to define constants at the module level and then code anywhere in that module can access those constants.  FYI, it's the same general concept as using `import` or `require` in the module.  You're initializing a module-level constant for use anywhere in that module.

Comment: Since it looks like you're interested in writing good code, this `if (iniparam.test(line) && line.match(iniparam)[1] === param) ` is quite inefficient.  You're matching your regex twice.  Just call `.match()` once and test the result to see if it's `null` to see if it matched before trying to use the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My simple recommendation would be to just define `iniparam` before the class definition.  Assuming this code is in a module, then variables at the module level are available for use anywhere in the module, but private beyond that (not available outside the module unless you export them).

This notion of declaring shared constants before a body of code that wants to use them is very common in Javascript modules.  You could even say that the practice of `import` or `require()` is doing the same thing - initializing some module-level constants that any code in the module can use.  It even can make things slightly more efficient for the interpreter because the constant is just created/initialized once when the module is initialized rather than every time some function is called (though if it's `const`, the interpreter might already optimize for that).

```
// declare shared constants
const iniparam = /^\s*([\w\.\-\_]+)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$/;

class iniparser {

    constructor (path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
    
    #getValue (data, param) {
        let value;
    
        data.toString().match(/.*?\n|.+$/g).forEach(function(line) {
            if (iniparam.test(line) && line.match(iniparam)[1] === param) {
                value = line.match(iniparam)[2];
            }
        });
    
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then, any code in this module will have access to the constant, but no code outside the module can access it.

---

Note, in addition to declaring `iniparam` as a shared constant, you could also make `getValue()` itself a module level utility function.  Since it doesn't seem to access instance data, it doesn't really need to be a method.  If `setValue()` also doesn't access instance data, it could also be a module-level utility function.

```
// declare shared constants
const iniparam = /^\s*([\w\.\-\_]+)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$/;

function getValue (data, param) {
    let value;

    data.toString().match(/.*?\n|.+$/g).forEach(function(line) {
        if (iniparam.test(line) && line.match(iniparam)[1] === param) {
            value = line.match(iniparam)[2];
        }
    });

    return value;
}

class iniparser {

    constructor (path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
    
}
```